# Laravel : Auth Login doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

Laravel : Auth Login doesn't seem to work

Here is my user controller

```
 UserController extends \BaseController
 function login() {       
        $input = Input::all();
        $credentials = array("username" => $input['username'], "password" => $input['password']);
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return Redirect::to("/home");
        } else {
            echo "Wrong";
        }
    }
```

but when It redirects to "/home", it cannot fetch the logged user

```
    HomeController extends \BaseController{

        function home(){
            var_dump(Auth::check()); //always return false
        }

    }
```

**EDIT:**
I think I got the answer. Here is my User Model

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

//    use UserTrait,
//        RemindableTrait;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = array('type', 'username', 'password', "name", "location", "photo_url");
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment', "user_id"); // this matches the Eloquent model
    }

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasOne('Post');
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
        return $this->username; // this is the reason why the login doesn't persists
    }

    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRememberToken() {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value) {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName() {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    public function getReminderEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

I changed

```
public function getAuthIdentifier() {
            return $this->username; 
        }
```

to :

```
public function getAuthIdentifier() {
                return $this->id; 
            }
```

And it worked!

Comment: What session driver are you using? Also are cookies enabled in your browser?

Comment: i'm using "file" as my session driver and cookies are enabled

Comment: Ok, in the console can you see the laravel session cookie being sent with the request headers when you are redirected to /home?

Comment: @rjmcb could you post the contents of your User model, your auth and session config, and a copy of the  User migration/schema you've used?

Comment: i think I got it. I'll edit my post for the answer